# Scala return variable type after future is complete Add Comment Collapse

Tags: scala, playframework

I've got a problem with returning a list after handling futures in scala. My code looks like this:

```
def getElements(arrayOfIds: Future[Seq[Int]]): Future[Seq[Element]] = {
    var elementArray: Seq[Element] = Seq()

    arrayOfIds.map {
      ids => ids.map(id => dto.getElementById(id).map {
                    case Some(element) => elementArray = elementArray :+ element
                    case None => println("Element not found")
                  })
    }
    arrayOfIds.onComplete(_ => elementArray)
  }
```

I'd like to do something like `.onComplete`, however the return type is 
 `Unit` and I'd like to return a `Future[Seq[Whatever]]`. Is there clean way to handle futures like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide the type of function `dto.getElementById`. If it is `Int => Future[Option[Element]]`, then:

```
def getElements(arrayOfIds: Future[Seq[Int]]): Future[Seq[Element]] = {
  val allElements: Future[Seq[Option[Element]]] = arrayOfIds.flatMap( ids =>
    Future.sequence(ids.map(dto.getElementById))
  )
  allElements.map(_.flatMap{
    case None => println();None
    case some => some
  })
}
```

Without logging, it would be:

```
arrayOfIds.flatMap( ids => Future.traverse(ids.map(dto.getElementById))(_.flatten))
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning the result to a mutable variable, return it from the continuation of the `Future`. You can use `flatMap` to extract only the `Element` results which actually contain a value:

```
def getElements(arrayOfIds: Future[Seq[Int]]): Future[Seq[Element]] = {
  arrayOfIds.flatMap(id => Future.fold(id.map(getElementById))(Seq.empty[Element])(_ ++ _))
}
```

Comment: Looks promising. I've got an error that says:
Type mismatch, expected: (Int) => GenTraversableOnce[NotInferedB], actual: (Int) => Future[Option[Element]]

Comment: @Felix Works for me with the following reproduce: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YuvalItzchakov/1TJl0Gm4TKy3SyDU36M24Q/1

Comment: getElementById returns a Future[Option[Element]] since it's a slick query.

Comment: @Felix Updated my answer accordingly